# Unnecessary Apache modules

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm attempting to configure apache to use a bit less memory. I'm wondering what you would consider to be either "heavy memory users" or just totally unnecessary when it comes to the loaded modules. I don't want to do anything yet, but so far I've commented out:

```
mod_status
mod_info
mod_userdir
mod_cern_meta
mod_asis
```

I'd love to get apache to run even lighter. Any recommendations? Sample conf files? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unnecessary is in the eye of the beholder, but the `--disable` rules in my compile of Apache 2.2 are:

```
include
filter
charset-lite
negotiation
asis
userdir
env
setenvif
status
autoindex
```

in addition to the modules that are off by default, and also the auth stuff as I do that entirely through scripts.

Comment: negotiation! took that guy out and "seems" to be much better.

Answer (score 2):

My rule of thumb is to not load any modules I'm not using.  However, this breaks down some if you're hosting sites controlled by others and need to keep things they *might* require loaded.

Comment: I'm the only site using this configuration so I can do whatever I like pretty much.